# MOSFET current mirror with compensation

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, current-mirror

I am trying to understand the difference between a MOSFET current mirror with and without compensation (Replace Q3 with a short circuit).

In the case of a current mirror without compensation, V1 needs to be increased for Q2 to enter the saturation region.

The addition of compensation means that the increase of V1 is no longer required. 
What is causing this to happen??

[image]